# I want to drop existing table space and add the freed space to the new table space in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, storage

I want to drop existing table space and add the freed space to the new table space in oracle.

I am trying drop an existing tablespace on oracle db, and then use the freed space for a new table space. can we directly assign this free space to new table space

Comment: you need two steps unless the tablespace you want to add space to is a bigfile, first drop the tablespace then add a new datafile to the tablespace you need space in.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on how the tablespace being enlarged is defined. At a minimum you will need to drop the first tablespace to free up space on your storage ([see here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DROP-TABLESPACE.html#GUID-C91F3E94-4503-48DE-9BCA-42E495E6BE11) for syntax):

```
drop tablespace old_tablespace [including contents and datafiles];
```

If the datafiles in the tablespace marked for growth were defined with `AUTOEXTEND` and still have room to grow (up to max size), then you need do nothing more. The files will automatically expand into the freed space as they have need. If they have already reached their maximum allowed size (32GB in most cases) then you will need to add a new file.

```
ALTER TABLESPACE tbs_03 ADD DATAFILE [... datafile options ...];
```

If the datafiles in the tablespace marked for growth were *not* defined with `AUTOEXTEND`, then you must add a new datafile, manually increase their size or enable autoextend, as appropriate.

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '/u02/oracle/rbdb1/stuff01.dbf' RESIZE 100M;
```

or

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '/u02/oracle/rbdb1/users03.dbf' AUTOEXTEND ON;
```